# Notification bar when you have questions with unaccepted answers of a certain age

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

I'm trying to keep up with all the new SE sites, but I was gently reminded this week on Gaming.stackexchange that I had a 0% accept rate. Oops.

I see that on your profile page it adds a warning message "Have you considered accepting an answer to this question?" after some period of time has passed, but I am betting that a lot of people don't look at their own profile pages all that frequently.

I suggest that you get the notification bar at the top of the screen whenever one of your questions hits the magic age where the notification already shows up next to the question on your profile page.

Comment: This could turn collosally annoying if there isn't also an age where it stops bothering you to accept. Sometimes, though admittedly rarely, there are just no good answers...

Comment: NaN (not another notification) please...

Comment: If it let you permanently dismiss the message either for a specific question or for all questions it would have less potential to annoy.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would be very interesting. I've forgotten to accept many questions and have only realized this when I sometimes check my profile or see my abnormally low accept rate.

However as @Chinmay said, something like this could get really annoying if its a constant reminder. Perhaps after a few days, you get the first reminder. Then when somebody posts a new answer, a day or two later it asks you again. There should be a way so that you don't get reminded more than once every 2 days, and a way to ignore these warnings for a particular question.

Comment: What if it was just another icon like the envelope in the bar at the top of the page?

Comment: ... That could work as well

Comment: Alternatively, if you could dismiss the notification and not get it again it would solve the problem.